# Blackfire profile cli scripts

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface, blackfire

I want to use blackfire to profile a php command of symfony.
I follow the getting started section just here https://blackfire.io/getting-started for mac os.

Then I create a file test.php with this content to test blackfire:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello World !";
```

but when I do

```
blackfire run php test.php
```

an error occured:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: blackfire: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: blackfire: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

if I remove the following code of my php.ini, i don't have any error but blackfire don't give me url to see the result of debug

```
[blackfire]
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/blackfire-php56/1.0.0/blackfire.so"
blackfire.agent_timeout = 0.25
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found my mistake,

```
$ php -v
```

give me

```
PHP 5.5.25 (cli)
[...]
```

and I installed the wrong version of blackfire

```
brew install blackfire-php56
```

so I unsinstall blackfire and re-install it

```
brew uninstall blackfire-php56
brew install blackfire-php55
```

finally I update my php.ini

```
[blackfire]
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/blackfire-php55/1.0.0/blackfire.so"
blackfire.agent_timeout = 0.25
```